# Is there a system/computational overhead when using AccuracySec=1s in systemd timers

Tags: performance, systemd-timers

`systemd` timers by default have 1 minute accuracy, however it is easy to change that with `AccuracySec` parameter in the timer definition.

I can't find any information related to whether setting accuracy to 1 second or less incurs penalty/overhead when compared to the default accuracy.